# Is a CMS like Drupal or WordPress appropriate for a basic data-centric web application?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, plugins

I'm curious if a CMS like Drupal or WordPress is a suitable approach for creating a data-centric web application.  It's nothing fancy, but would require a login to access, and essentially have search parameters, results pages, and detail pages.  I can program this pretty easily but would prefer to just theme Drupal or WP, since I'm not much of a designer.  Thanks for any insight, as well as any examples of where this might currently exist!

-e-

Comment: unless your data-centric application isn't suitable to publish data on blog posts and provide logged-in users chance to comment and share contents, I would preffer to write it on your own. so the answer is: "it depends.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, Drupal is suited for data-centric websites. [Development Seed](http://developmentseed.org/) is a company that [use Drupal](http://developmentseed.org/sectors/open-source-drupal) and make data-centric websites but they also use other technologies such as Node.JS. As suggested by Marek Sebera, it really depends on your actual needs and what exactly your site will be doing with the data.

You basically have two ways to integrate your data into Drupal. One is to import the data into Drupal as [entities](http://drupal.org/glossary#entity) (a generic concept for anything data in Drupal 7) or [nodes](http://drupal.org/glossary#node) (a concrete concept for anything *content* in Drupal). The other is to directly query an external data source from Drupal.

To import data, the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module is a very solid and flexible solution. Out of the box it *only* supports CSV, Atom and RSS from local files or HTTP. But it is flexible and extensible and there is already many [contributed modules](http://drupal.org/node/856644) that extends it.

To query the data, both external or imported, you can use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to build query pages. For external data source support, you will need [additional *backends* modules](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_multisitesearch/views%20backend?filters=ss_meta_type%3amodule) and probably have to write your own.

If you import the data as entities, you can also uses the *core*'s [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) to write your own query without using Views. And you can also uses the [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) to index the imported data using a search engine such a [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: Thanks.  This tells me a lot about how I would go about doing it, and also tells me that I may be best off building it as a custom application, since there is a lot of the Drupal infrastructure that the development will have to support that I won't really be using.  Thanks for an insightful response.

Comment: what about WordPress ? I need wordpress in a data centric website.Is that  also able to hold the load and still process results in good time ?